# Getting java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "517838839328"

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, cucumber

```
PageUtil.clickOnButton(driver, AppXPathsConstants.UserAdminAddNewuser);

String id ="1517838839328";
String newid = "1517838839328" + (Integer.parseInt(id.substring(1,id.length()))+1);

PageUtil.inputFieldEntry(driver, user_id,newid);
```

1. First line I clck on Add button
2. Second line I enter the id
3. Third line I am incrementing the id value by 1
4. Fourth line is newid value which contains the incremented value

But it is not getting incremented and I am getting the java.lang.NumberFormatException.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum number you can parse to integer is
`2147483647` while you're trying to parse 200 times bigger number

Try to use `Long.parseLong()` instead.